# How to clear the cache while clearing localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have set a Authentication token in local storage on login and clears it on logout. After logout if the user tries to login again, old authentication token taken from the cache is taken instead of newly set value. How to clear the cache while clearing localstorage. I am using angular 2 in my application.

Login:

```
localstorage.setItem("token", "value")
```

Logout:

```
localstorage.clear();
```

Comment: you need to clear to token from in memory in ur js code

Comment: I have tried localstorage.removeItem("token") as well. STill facing same issue

Comment: do you store the token in memory anny where like in a variable somwhere ?

Comment: like in ur auth service

Comment: @TimCodes - I'm also facing the same issue. Identical issue in `ReactJs` - `OIDC Client` of Identity Server.

Comment: @TimCodes : I am storing a token in variable

Comment: @selvassn make sure you clearing that varible when the user logs out eg. var authTok = "sdg6565-dsgsdg-klkl" when user logs out authTok = ""

Comment: @TimCodes I have tried it. No luck

Comment: Check in dev tools if the token is really deleted from the local storage on log out

Comment: yes its deleted. If i clear the cache new token is taken up

Comment: are you storing user creds anywhere?

Comment: @selvassn can you try using `localstorage.removeItem('token')` instead of clear

Comment: @TimCodes : No i am not storing the credentials anywhere

Comment: @RahulSingh: yes ... still its not working

Answer (score 1):

before doing **localstorage.clear();**, you have to remove the element; To do that, your code should look like this:
localStorage.removeItem('Token');
localstorage.clear();

Note that if you are using BehaviorSubject, you also have to set it to null;
assume the following:

```
private loggedInUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
public loggedInUser: Observable<User>;
```

and in the constructor, to get the user's value:

```
this.loggedInUserSubject= new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser')));
this.loggedInUser= this.loggedInUserSubject.asObservable();
```

then to logout:

```
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    localstorage.clear();
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

How are you so confident that logout will happen?
What if user will just close the browser?

I suggest to save a time stamp in addition to the security token
and give like time out for the credentials.

```
localStorage['token_time'] = ''+myDate.getTime();
// And to restore it :
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(localStorage['token_time'], 10));
```